# If value from database on user is 0 then execute php code

Tags: php, mysql, session

Hi guys i'm quite new to PHP but I'm currently working on this site and I want it to check if the total_online_time for the user is 0 or less then it should execute the script which will create a room for the user. However after trying with this script the .php page won't load.

http://pastebin.com/XDLhFvtE

```
<?php
$getStats = mysql_query("SELECT total_online_time FROM `users` WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['user']['id']."'");
if ($getStats > 0)
$getRoomKit = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM room_starterkit ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"));
$getRoom = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `rooms` WHERE id = '".$randomRoomID['id']."' LIMIT 1"));
$welcomeMessage = "Welcome " . $_SESSION['user']['username'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `rooms` (caption,owner_id,description,model_name,wallpaper,floor) VALUES ('".$welcomeMessage."', '".$_SESSION['user']['id']."', 'Welcome to Hablore', '".$getRoomKit['room_Model']."', '".$getRoomKit['room_Wallpaper']."', '".$getRoomKit['room_Floor']."') ");
$theRoomID = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `rooms` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1"));
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `home_room` = '".$theRoomID['id']."' WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION['user']['id']."'");
$getRoomItems = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM room_itemkits WHERE roomKit = '".$getRoomKit['id']."'");

    while($CurItem = mysql_fetch_assoc($getItems)){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `items` (user_id, room_id, base_item, extra_data, x, y, z, rot, wall_pos) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['user']['id']."','".$lastRoomID['id']."','".$CurItem['base_item']."','".$CurItem['extra_data']."','".$CurItem['x']."','".$CurItem['y']."','".$CurItem['z']."','".$CurItem['rot']."','".$CurItem['wall_pos']."')");
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: It seems to me that every table you select from, you select from `ID`. Its fine, peacy and perhaps even *perfect*. Now read on how to use [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) in mysql. Secondly, why are you using [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)? The reason why I'm asking is highlighted in red, if you venture on by clicking that link. On a *side note* red is a color to tell you its **not** good. Some might even go so far to tell you a kitten is strangled each time you use that function.

Comment: On a side note, its been highlighted in red for the past **3** and a *half* ---**years**---, kinda hard to miss.